# backup shoping cart HTML java script image files every day cron

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

i want backup shooing cart HTML java script image files every day

how to write a corn job for automatic every day at night backup code

thanks

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. Please use 5 minutes to learn how to make a good question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

One of the simpliest methods is to write a bash script and add it to crontab.

**Example:**

```
#!/bin/bash
WEBSITE_PATH=/home/user/domains/site.com # path to your scripts
BACKUP_PATH=/home/user/backups # path to backup directory

zip -r $BACKUP_PATH/backup_`date +%Y-%m-%d`.zip $WEBSITE_PATH
```

This script will create a .zip archive with backup of your files with filename `backup_YYYY-MM-DD.zip`.

You need to add executable permissions to this script (`chmod +x script.sh`) and after that you can add it to your crontab (`crontab -e`) by adding following line:

`0 3 * * * PATH_TO_SCRIPT.SH >/dev/null 2>&1`

It will execute written script every night at 3 AM.

It's a good start and very simple mechanism.